# Force button element to layout like div

Tags: css, webkit

I am trying to replace div elements with button elements to improve accessibility, but I need the buttons to layout like the divs used to do. (note this only needs to work in webkit)

The div takes the width of the parent container, while the button only takes the place needed to display its content.

How can I change that?

I would not like to set something like width: 100%, because if you are using more then one button in a container with display: webkit-box the divs nicely layout to use remaining space.

Here is a small **example**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>button test</title>
        <style>
            .mybutton{
                display: block;
                border: 1px solid red;
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                background-color: transparent;
                -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #A8ACB9),color-stop(1, #eee));
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="mybutton">Div Button</div>

        <button class="mybutton">Button</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your button is in a container with "display: -webkit-box" then just add "-webkit-box-flex: 1" to the button (or any elements) within that container. This solves it.

http://jsfiddle.net/y53VT/

Comment: I can`t add a container. I need the button to layout the same in my small example without changing the dom structure

Comment: Seems it's not possible without changing the DOM to add an outer container. Been tinkering with it for awhile. The button element shrinks to fit it's content unless its given an explicit dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have backward slashes on your `-webkit` rules. Remove them and they will behave the same as divs, except for some inherited styles that need to be resetted.

You can see an example of buttons and inputs playing nicely with webkit box here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dt592/

Comment: with the surrounding div set to display: -webkit-box. It works fine, without it though they render differently. I can`t add a surrounding div.

Comment: -webkit-box is added to a parent container, not to the elements that are flexible, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/

Comment: yes I know, but in my case I can`t change the display of the parent

Comment: They are expected to work like posted in the example. Expand horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go more specific. Try `button.mybutton {` in your css...

Comment: the styles are applied just fine. So matching more specific won`t change anything. Thanks anyway :)